# Upgrading Null Mysteriis to be on par with third tier Hunter organizations

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, hunter-the-vigil

I'm stating up a character for a Third Tier campaign of Hunter: the Vigil, and my eyes have fallen on Null Mysteriis as the perfect group for my character to align with. The issue with this being that, especially as a non-combatant, I imagine I'll be punching below my weight in a *third tier* campaign. I feel I receive far fewer benefits from my compact, compared to my compatriots conspiracies.

So my question is, how do I push my compact to compete with conspiracy level characters, within the rules, or potentially how have you houseruled this? Please follow the guidelines of Good Subjective, and use personal experience or references in this case.

I will be asking my about GM this, but as I've not met them yet I think it'd be more productive  to come to the table with ideas and reasonable suggestions that they can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lobby for the use of the materials in COMPACTS AND CONSPIRACIES**

If you're going to be working with third-tier companions, the alternate systems present in the *Compacts and Conspiracies* write-up can help fill in some of the gaps in raw power. The "I'm Doing Science" alternate endowment allows, once per session, for an NM member to spend five minutes analyzing evidence for a concrete lead, clue, or dice advantage against a monster, while the "Behold My Monstrous Evidence!" writeup gives you leeway to use scientific techniques on unnatural materials in creative ways. It's not magical artifacts or super-technology, but it's a nice bit of compensation.

Comment: This is really good, but is it enough? Are the endowments enough to fill the gap?

Comment: @Pureferret Not completely, no. The trouble is that NM has a paradigm that really requires buy-in from the Storyteller and the other players to not end up "the guy who's wrong about everything nearly all the time." This measure will help ensure that you're useful and relevant while establishing your theories and doing research that helps the group, but Tier 3 is basically full-on supernatural-level power, meant to beat monsters on their own level, and you're not there.

Comment: Every paranormal investigators group needs a Fox Mulder.

Comment: @Nigralbus Yeah, but the NM are Dana Scullys; they reject belief in favor of the scientific explanation as a matter of course.

Comment: @Jadasc I can see how this could be a problem in the WoD...

Comment: @Jadasc, what about the open-minders and the Cataclysmics?